# Catching the selectionChanged() signal of a QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, qt4

I am trying to catch the signal that indicates that the user has used the rubberband to select a region. I tried this:

```
  QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene();

  connect(scene, SIGNAL(selectionChanged()), this, SLOT(SelectionChanged()));
  this->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
  this->graphicsView->setDragMode(QGraphicsView::RubberBandDrag);
```

but my SelectionChanged() slot is never called. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order the signal [`selectionChanged`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#selectionChanged) to be emitted whenever some items in the scene get selected. In order to get selected the flag `QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable` should have been set.

Are you sure the items are selectable?

Comment: There are actually no items in the scene currently. It sounded like here: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsscene.html#selectionChanged that it also is emited when a "selection area is set", which I thought the rubberband was doing?

Comment: The selectionChanged() signal indicates that a QGraphicsItem in your scene has had its selection state changed.  If the user did not select any items with the rubberband, then selection hasn't changed, and thus no signal emitted.

Comment: Ok, then the question becomes "How do I catch the event of the rubberband associated with the GraphicsView being used/released?"

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments of @webclectic answer, the `QGraphicsView` rubber band is for selecting `QGraphicsItems`.

For getting the coordinates of a rubber band, you would need inherit `QGraphicsView` then follow the instructions on the [`QRubberBand` manual page](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qrubberband.html#details), storing the coordinates on mouse press and release, and then fire a signal with the QRect of the points.

Comment: For future readers, I implemented this here: http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/Qt/Images/RubberBandSignal